# history.validation_data is None even though I added x_val and y_val in fit method

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to train a variational autoencoder on cifar10 dataset. This is an extract of my script:

```
# Load the CIFAR-10 dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Split the data into training, validation, and test sets
validation_size = 0.2  
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=validation_size)

# Define the model
vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=Adam())
history = vae.fit(x_train, epochs=2, batch_size=128, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

But unfortunately if I access `history.validation_data` I get `None`, indeed `history.validation_data is None` is `True`.

How's that and how do I fix?

Comment: validation_data is not a property of History object that .fit() method returns.

Comment: @GiorgosLivanos I was asking since Val loss is weirdly stuck at 0 during training

Comment: I see. This could happen for several reasons but I would suggest you to start a new question because it is out of this question's scope. What seems a little bit weird though, is that you have not passed y_train in Model.fit.

Comment: @GiorgosLivanos I posted a new question

Comment: Would you provide the shapes of your arrays: x_train, x_val

Comment: And why are you passing the y_val in your validation data? It should be homogeneous to the x_train in fit calling